# During a "sudo apt-get upgrade", how should I answer this prompt about a change to the 20auto-upgrades configuration file?

Tags: ubuntu, apt, upgrade

[image]

Which option should I select ??[image: This is the option for show 3 way difference between versions]

Answer (score 0):

In the previous dialog, select

```
install the package maintainer's version
```

Unless you ever made a change to that file, there's no need in keeping it.